# How to implement variable with value operator statement in IF statement?

Tags: php

How to implement variable with value operator statement in IF statement ?

```
    if ($dcustomer['mix_max']=='MIN') {
            $operator=">=";
         } elseif ($dcustomer['mix_max']=='MAX') {
            $operator="<=";
        }


        if ($djml['Tamount'] ."$operator". $dcustomer['limit_maksimal']){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot (well, you could if you used [eval()](http://www.php.net/eval), which should be avoided for obvious reasons).

But the same effect can be achieved with a multiplier:

```
switch ($dcustomer['mix_max']) {
    case 'MIN':
        $multiplier = 1;
        break;
    case 'MAX':
        $multiplier = -1;
        break;
    default:
        // Always prepare for the unknown :-)
        throw new \Exception("Unknown operator");
 }
 if ($djml['Tamount']*$multiplier >= $dcustomer['limit_maksimal']*$multiplier) {
     ...
 }
```

But I think it would be clearer and more flexible:

```
$condition = null;
switch ($dcustomer['mix_max']) {
    case 'MIN':
        $condition = ($djml['Tamount'] >= $dcustomer['limit_maksimal']);
        break;
    case 'MAX':
        $condition = ($djml['Tamount'] <= $dcustomer['limit_maksimal']);
        break;
    default:
        // Always prepare for the unknown :-)
        throw new \Exception("Unknown operator");
 }
 if ($condition) {
     ...
 }
```

Comment: That is because your array does not contain `mix_max`. I cannot help you there: you said there was an element called `mix_max`, you are responsible to supply it. Is it possible that you made a mistake and the correct name is **min_max** by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$dcustomer = array("mix_max"=>"MIN","limit_maksimal"=>2);
$djml = array("Tamount"=>"");

if ($dcustomer['mix_max']=='MIN') {
    $operator=">=";
} elseif ($dcustomer['mix_max']=='MAX') {
    $operator="<=";
}


echo $djml['Tamount'] .$operator. $dcustomer['limit_maksimal'];
```